# Only ccs styling of container which has specific number of children elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, frontend, web-frontend

Is there any specific css selector to style container which contains specific numbers of children. For example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So I need to apply 'justify-content: flex-start;' to .container only if it has 1, 5, 6 or 7 children. At other cases it has to contain 'justify-content: center;' property

Comment: Use javascript ?

Comment: Do you know the number of items youre going to be rendering?

Comment: - I want to know if it is possible to implement this without JS.
- I have the set of numbers, which were mentioned.

Comment: nop, CSS is about styling and never sees the dom using it. This is a javascript job if it has to be sorted out on the fly, else , use an attribute in the markup so CSS can be applied from it.

Comment: are you OK with some hacks? I may have a solution for your specific case

Answer (score -1):

If you know the number of items youre about to render, add it as data attribute and use it for styling.

```css
.container {
  justify-content: center;
}

.container[data-itemcount="1"],
.container[data-itemcount="5"].,
.container[data-itemcount="6"],
.container[data-itemcount="7"] {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-itemcount="3">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-itemcount="4">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-itemcount="5">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-itemcount="7">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have this way. But is there some specific selector for solvation. Without additional changes to template, using JS and so on?

Comment: No, you can target a specific child in a container but you can not target a container from its contents in css only. Its kinda only "outside in", never "Inside out".

Comment: So implementation with data-attribute will be the best. Thanks.